# Java Bean not updating unless refreshing the page

Tags: ajax, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

I'm just a rookie, and I'm trying to learn JSP (I'm using scriptlet), servlet, beans and Ajax.
I'm validating some registration forms by calling a servlet (through Ajax). Every time a character is inserted, the Ajax function is recalled and "value" is sent to a servlet whose job is to check if this value is OK. The servlet gets an HttpSession, then it operates on the passed value and saves it into a bean and finally sets `session.setAttribute("bean_name", bean)`. In JSP I inserted the `jsp:usebean` tag with scope=session. I got no problem retrieving values, for example `<%= bean.getUsername()%>`, but the problem is all the form values **don't get updated unless I refresh the page**.

What could it be?

Comment: Bean values are fetched on page render. If you would want values on view to update without refresh. You may use ajax to to reRender a particular field .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You make the AJAX call to the Servlet. The Servlet does what it needs to do, and renders a response. However, the AJAX call was made by means of JavaScript, *after* the page was already rendered.

What you need to do is to edit the JavaScript code that issues the AJAX call. Once the AJAX call takes place, your JavaScript code has to wait until a response is returned from the Servlet, and then use client-side facilities (such as DHTML) to edit the already-rendered page.

Comment: I'm attempting to do that, but I still haven't figured it out. I tried JSF and it worked smoothly, but, since it's a project and I'm not allowed to use JSF, I wish you could show me some example or give me some other hints.
Also setting `xmlhttp.open("GET","servlet?x=y",false);` won't solve the problem.